# Disable button once added to cart - Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

In a list of products there is an "Add to cart" button for each product. When I click the button it gets disabled. But when I click the button for another product the button of the previous product is enabled again. How can I make sure the previous button remains disabled?

**HTML code**

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2" type="button"
                    (click)="btnAddToCart(prod)" [disabled]="itemExists===prod.Id">Add To Cart
</button>
```

**component.ts code**

```js
itemExists: number;

btnAddToCart(product: ProductList) {
  this.cartService.addToCart(product);
    if (product.Id) {
      this.itemExists = product.Id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some way to keep track of a list of product ids instead of just the most recent, which is what your code currently does.

One suggestion is to change `itemExists` into an array and use it to hold all of the ids that have been added.

```
itemExists: number[] = [];

btnAddToCart(product: ProductList) {
  this.cartService.addToCart(product);
    if (product.Id && !itemExists.includes(product.id)) {
        this.itemExists.push(product.Id);
    }
}
```

Your buttons can the determine their state with a small logic change that checks to see if the array includes the current product.id.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-2" type="button"
    (click)="btnAddToCart(prod)" [disabled]="itemExists.includes(prod.Id)">Add To Cart
</button>
```

Remember that if you remove any item from the cart, the id must be removed from the array - if that makes sense for your app.